# Does knowing $g, g^r, g^{r^2}, g^{r^3}, \dotsc$ sometimes offer a significant advantage in finding $r$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms

Is there a cyclic group $\mathcal G$ with generator $g$ for which the discrete log problem is assumed to be hard, but knowing $g, g^r, g^{r^2}, g^{r^3}, \dotsc$ for random $r$ makes finding $r$ easy?

This might be related: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2014-83-288/S0025-5718-2014-02813-5/S0025-5718-2014-02813-5.pdf
The best it seems to offer is $O(p^{1/2})$ which is $n/2$ bits of improvement where $p$ is the order of $\mathcal G$ and $n$ is the number of bits in $p$.

The question boils down to: is there a family of groups for which the Discrete Log problem is hard but the Strong Discrete Log problem is easy, much in the same way as there are families of groups where the Decisional Diffie-Hellman problem is tractable and the Discrete Log problem is intractable?

Comment: What is $p$ and $n$ ? It seems to me that the linked article calls it the "stong discrete logarithm" and it discusses the issue. (I have not read beyond the first page). What exactly is your question ?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich $p$ is the order of the group which is assumed to be prime. $n$ is the number of bits in $p$. What else do you consider unclear?

Comment: It is clearer now. Please include the definition of $n$ and $p$ in the question by editing it.